# RavenDB "Connection Was Reset" - After Enabling SSL

Tags: ssl, https, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I am having some trouble with RavenDB after enabling SSL. I have followed the instructions on the RavenDB documentation for enabling SSL which can be found [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/all/server/configuration/enabling-ssl).

Namely, I updated the Raver.Server.exe.config file to include the new setting and I also installed the cert using `/installSSL` on Raven.Server.exe.

If I disable SSL - everything works fine, but once I **enable SSL** I get a `connection was reset` message in the browser.[image]

I have enabled the Raven logs with the Nlog.config file and also checked the event viewer for logs. Neither of these two have any information. The RavenDB service is running, but it just won't connect when I go to the studio. The problem is beyond the studio because I can't get our APIs to connect to it either.

I have been searching around for a couple of days, but I can't find anything, anywhere.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this error occurs when the SSL cert has not been installed correctly into the Windows Cert Store. After inspecting the cert store, I found that the cert was not installed correctly into the Personal collection.

It might be important to note that I disabled SSL on RavenDB and then fixed the Cert Store.

After installing the cert, I re-enabled SSL on RavenDB and everything was working fine again.